# MS-Word: How to disable copy&paste popup button?

Tags: ms-word

Whenever I paste something copied before I get this button popping up:
[image] Most of the time it is exactly at the wrong spot and I have to press "Esc" to hide it before I can read my text under it again.

Is there any way to completely disable this popup button?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes." However, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: You are welcome. I see you did post in SuperUser. I did not make the rules here. I do not especially like them.

Answer (score -1):

The button can be disabled under File/Options/Advanced:

[image]

Comment: The question in Super User was the place for your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic